# VBA in Excel - Internet Explorer download XML - Save As Dialog

Tags: excel, vba

I am downloading Climate XML data into Excel 2013. I need to automate the process and I can navigate immediately to the correct page preloaded with the correct parameters. I can click on the OK button but then the Internet Explorer - Open/Save/Cancel dialogue box comes up.

I have tried various option in Windows 7 to trap the Windows event 32770 (??) but am I unsure how to code this. I just want to save the file as `c:\temp.xml`.

I don't want to use the `SendKeys` method as it is too unreliable. Can anyone suggest a way to handle the dialog ?

```
Dim htm As Object
Dim IE As Object

Dim Doc As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/exportEntry.do?form=transaction&destinationAccountHolder=&startDate=01%2F06%2F2009&destinationRegistry=-1&originatingAccountType=-1&endDate=01%2F05%2F2010&transactionID=&suppTransactionType=-1&originatingAccountHolder=&transactionType=-1&languageCode=en&destinationAccountNumber=&destinationAccountType=-1&toCompletionDate=&originatingRegistry=-1&destinationAccountIdentifier=&fromCompletionDate=&originatingAccountIdentifier=&transactionStatus=4&originatingAccountNumber=8&currentSortSettings="

Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set Doc = IE.document

Doc.getelementbyID("btnOK").Click

Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33484763/2165759) may be helpful.