# Automate Save As File with IUIAutomation in Internet Explorer 9+

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, save-as, notification-bar

There are 63 entries on Stack Overflow related to "IE VBA Save-as" topic.
That is to automate the Download Notification Bar of IE 9+.

Several methods are recommended to automate this process.
Method 1. using XMLHttp   ([example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110949/vba-in-excel-internet-explorer-download-xml-save-as-dialogue), applied to sites that show the direct url of to-be-downloaded file)
Method 2. using autoitx.dll to send hotkeys (example link, not so stable based on my experience)
Method 3. using IUIAutomation ([blogspot link](http://faidootdoot.blogspot.jp/2015/04/excel-vba-automate-save-as-file-using.html) )

I think Method 3 is suitable for most of these situations. 
However, I have NOT successfully tried this method, because
1) I can't add reference to  UIAutomationCore.dll 
   I get this dll under C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and the project(*.xlsm) folder
   **Question1**:Please tell me how to add reference to  UIAutomationCore.dll.

2) Subroutine Download_Save_As in the page ([blogspot link](http://faidootdoot.blogspot.jp/2015/04/excel-vba-automate-save-as-file-using.html) ) uses sending shortkeys to navigate to the save-as window.
    I don't thinks this is stable enough as I tried the AutoitX way.
    **Question2**:Is it possible to click the save-as option by using purely IUIAutomation way? and how to?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the file in reference library and move it where it is looking. You can hover on a reference to see where they are kept. I don't know why this particular reference's location is different.