# How can I automate Save as dialog box in IE11 using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to download some data on carbon emissions. I can preload the page with the relevant settings via the URL.
It loads fine and I can click the OK button by its ID then I get the IE11 - Open/Save/Cancel Dialogue at the bottom. I have tried all suggestions using FindWindows (#32770) and also Send Keys which is very unreliable. Can someone suggest the code to manipulate this dialogue box or else perhaps examine the HTML on the web page to see if a direct download would be possible?

```
Dim htm As Object
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/exportEntry.do?form=accountAll&permitIdentifier=&accountID=&installationIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&account.registryCodes=CY&primaryAuthRep=&searchType=account&identifierInReg=&mainActivityType=&buttonAction=&account.registryCode=&languageCode=en&installationName=&accountHolder=&accountStatus=&accountType=&action=&registryCode="
Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set Doc = IE.document
Doc.getelementbyID("btnOK").Click [embed=file 884739]

'I need code here which clicks the save as button as save the file as C:\temp.xml

Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: I've launched your code, and page returned the error "99655 records, exceeds the predefined limit of 3000. Please refine your criteria and try again.", no downloading starts. Could you fix the link? Also take a look [at this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32429348/2165759).

Comment: HI Dear Friend, I updated code with working URL. Please check once again.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim strExportURL As String
    Dim strFormData As Variant
    Dim strContent As String
    Dim arrRespBody() As Byte

    ' build exportURL parameter
    strExportURL = Join(Array( _
        "permitIdentifier=", _
        "accountID=", _
        "form=accountAll", _
        "installationIdentifier=", _
        "complianceStatus=", _
        "account.registryCodes=CY", _
        "primaryAuthRep=", _
        "searchType=account", _
        "identifierInReg=", _
        "mainActivityType=", _
        "buttonAction=", _
        "account.registryCode=", _
        "languageCode=en", _
        "installationName=", _
        "accountHolder=", _
        "accountStatus=", _
        "accountType=", _
        "action=", _
        "registryCode=" _
    ), "&")

    ' build the whole form data
    strFormData = Join(Array( _
        "languageCode=en", _
        "exportURL=" & EncodeUriComponent(strExportURL), _
        "form=accountAll", _
        "exportType=1", _
        "OK=Ok" _
    ), "&")

    ' POST XHR to retrieve the content
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/export.do", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send strFormData
        arrRespBody = .ResponseBody
        ' strRespText = .ResponseText
        ' strRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        ' strStatus = .Status
    End With

    ' some processing examples

    ' convert to string
    strContent = BinaryToText(arrRespBody, "utf-8")
    ' replace LF symbols with CRLF for line breaks to be displayed right
    strContent = Replace(strContent, vbLf, vbCrLf)
    ' show in notepad
    ShowInNotepad strContent

    ' save to temp.xml file on the desktop folder
    SaveBinaryToFile arrRespBody, CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders.Item("Desktop") & "\temp.xml"

End Sub

Function EncodeUriComponent(sText)
    With CreateObject("ScriptControl")
        .Language = "JScript"
        EncodeUriComponent = .Run("encodeURIComponent", sText)
    End With
End Function

Sub ShowInNotepad(strToFile)
    Dim strTempPath
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strTempPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") & "\" & .GetTempName
        With .CreateTextFile(strTempPath, True, True)
            .WriteLine (strToFile)
            .Close
        End With
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe " & strTempPath, 1, True
        .DeleteFile (strTempPath)
    End With
End Sub

Function BinaryToText(arrBytes() As Byte, strCharSet As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write arrBytes
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Charset = strCharSet
        BinaryToText = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub SaveBinaryToFile(arrBytes() As Byte, strPath As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write arrBytes
        .SaveToFile strPath, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And this will work for only XML files and restricted to only this URL. Now I need to give dynamic site and download excel files with save as option(need to rename). can you give me idea about it. I am using IE 11

Comment: There is no common case in creating XHR, each time you have to make some reverse-engineering work, since each web site has it's own particular design and functionality. If you have one more link, then create one more question.