# Alternative to URLDownloadtofile when automating IE with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using InternetExplorer.application with Excel VBA for quite a while with few issues.  One problem I have is downloading a file from website.  I can get as far as having the "Open/Save As" buttons appear but that is where I am stuck.

I've tried using URLDownloadToFile and it does not seem to work through the same session as the InternetExplorer.application objects that I have.  It usually returns the HTML text for a webpage stating that authentication is required.  If I have multiple browsers open and some of the old ones are already authenticated then it will download the file most of the time.

Is there a way to download the file using the InternetExplorer.application object itself?  If not, is there some way I can associate the URLDownloadtofile function with the object that is already authenticated and logged into the website?

EDIT:

The code I've been using is:

```
    IE2.navigate ("https://...")
    strURL = "https://..."
    strPath = "c:\..."
    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)
```

I've also tried:

```
    Do While IE2.Readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    SendKeys "%S"
    IE2.ExecWB OLECMDID_SAVEAS, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
```

And:

```
    Dim Report As Variant
    Report = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("c:\...", "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
```

No success in any of these, except for the first one which sometimes saves the actual file, but sometimes saves the website that states the authentication error.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Please provide some code, how have you used URLDownloadToFile? Generally the right URL provided to XHR is enough to downoad a file.

Comment: Done.  I've been working with various codes to search through windows and attempt to find the handle.  Most recently I started using:http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=52 to try to at least see how windows and handles are changing when the download option (IE11) is available or not.  Not seeing any differences in the outputs with these two conditions though.  "Download option" is the box at the bottom of IE that appears to select open/save as/cancel.

Comment: How do you get `strURL`? Is it a direct link to the file to be downloaded? Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33556335/2165759), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32429348/2165759) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33484763/2165759) answers.

Comment: It's a direct link but I need to authenticate through other pages first.  I believe that if I am somehow able to pass that authentication through to URLDownloadToFile then it would solve my problem.  I'll take a look at the links, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve similar issue with some JavaScript.

The first step is to make JavaScript download the content of the file into a binary array (it doesn't require another authentication once the user is already authenticated).

Then, I needed to pass this binary array back to VBA. I didn't know the other way, so I print the content of this array into a temporary DIV element (with JavaScript) as a string and then read it with VBA and convert it back to binary array.

Finally, I re-created the file from the given binary array by using ADODB.Stream class.

---

The time required to download a single file grows geometrically with the size of this file. Therefore, **this method is not suitable for large files (> 3MB)**, since it tooks more than 5 minutes then to download a single file.

---

Below is the code to do that:

```
'Parameters:
' * ie - reference to the instance of Internet Explorer, where the user is already authenticated.
' * sourceUrl - URL to the file to be downloaded.
' * destinationPath - where the file should be saved.
'Be aware that the extension of the file given in [destinationPath] parameter must be
'consistent with the format of file being downloaded. Otherwise the function below will
'crash on the line: [.SaveToFile destinationPath, 2]
Public Function saveFile(ie As Object, sourceUrl As String, destinationPath As String)
    Dim binData() As Byte
    Dim stream As Object
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    binData = getDataAsBinaryArray(ie, sourceUrl)

    Set stream = VBA.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With stream
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .write binData
        .SaveToFile destinationPath, 2
    End With

End Function



Private Function getDataAsBinaryArray(Window As Object, Path As String) As Byte()
    Const TEMP_DIV_ID As String = "div_binary_transfer"
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim resultDiv As Object
    Dim binAsString As String
    Dim offset As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim binArray() As Byte
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Execute JavaScript code created automatically by function [createJsScript] in
    'the given Internet Explorer window.
    Call Window.Document.parentWindow.execScript(createJsScript(TEMP_DIV_ID, Path), "JavaScript")

    'Find the DIV with the given id, read its content to variable [binAsString]
    'and then convert it to array strArray - it is declared as String()
    'in order to make it possible to use function [VBA.Split].
    Set resultDiv = Window.Document.GetElementById(TEMP_DIV_ID)
    binAsString = VBA.Left(resultDiv.innerhtml, VBA.Len(resultDiv.innerhtml) - 1)
    strArray = VBA.Split(binAsString, ";")


    'Convert the strings from the [strArray] back to bytes.
    offset = LBound(strArray)
    ReDim binArray(0 To (UBound(strArray) - LBound(strArray)))
    For i = LBound(binArray) To UBound(binArray)
        binArray(i) = VBA.CByte(strArray(i + offset))
    Next i


    getDataAsBinaryArray = binArray


End Function


'Function to generate JavaScript code doing three tasks:
' - downloading the file with given URL into binary array,
' - creating temporary DIV with id equal to [divId] parameter,
' - writing the content of binary array into this DIV.
Private Function createJsScript(divId As String, url As String) As String

    createJsScript = "(function saveBinaryData(){" & vbCrLf & _
                        "//Create div for holding binary array." & vbCrLf & _
                        "var d = document.createElement('div');" & vbCrLf & _
                        "d.id = '" & divId & "';" & vbCrLf & _
                        "d.style.visibility = 'hidden';" & vbCrLf & _
                        "document.body.appendChild(d);" & vbCrLf & _
                        "var req = null;" & vbCrLf & _
                        "try { req = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}" & vbCrLf & _
                        "if (!req) try { req = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); } catch(e) {}" & vbCrLf & _
                        "if (!req) try { req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); } catch(e) {}" & vbCrLf & _
                        "req.open('GET', '" & url & "', false);" & vbCrLf & _
                        "req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');" & vbCrLf & _
                        "req.send(null);" & vbCrLf & _
                        "var filestream = req.responseText;" & vbCrLf & _
                        "var binStream = '';" & vbCrLf & _
                        "var abyte;" & vbCrLf & _
                        "for (i = 0; i < filestream.length; i++){" & vbCrLf & _
                        "    abyte = filestream.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;" & vbCrLf & _
                        "    binStream += (abyte + ';');" & vbCrLf & _
                        "}" & vbCrLf & _
                        "d.innerHTML = binStream;" & vbCrLf & _
                    "})();"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
Public Sub OpenWebXLS()
' *************************************************
' Define Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' *************************************************
Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksWebWorkSheet As Worksheet

Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

' *************************************************
' Open The Web Workbook
' *************************************************
Workbooks.Open ("http://www.sportsbookreviewsonline.com/scoresoddsarchives/nba/nba%20odds%202015-16.xlsx")

' *************************************************
' Set the Web Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' *************************************************
Set wkbWebWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksWebWorkSheet = ActiveSheet

' *************************************************
' Copy The Web Worksheet To My Workbook and Rename
' *************************************************
wksWebWorkSheet.Copy After:=wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "MyNewWebSheet"

' *************************************************
' Close the Web Workbook
' *************************************************
wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```