# Is there a way to download image files from the internet using VBA on Mac?

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

I’ve tried so many different ways to try and download images from set URLs using VBA on Mac but I keep coming up stumps. I need to download images into a certain folder automatically to be used in a user form. I can download it seems anything but images on Mac! Does anyone have any pointers please?

Comment: Downloading files shouldn't be any different on a mac. Please include the code you have tried in your question if you need help with it.

Comment: I’ve tried URLDownloadToFile but that is a windows only function and followhyperlink but with pictures it just loads the web browser rather than downloads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336507/alternative-to-urldownloadtofile-when-automating-ie-with-vba

Comment: I have never used `URLDownloadToFile` but it looks like you have to provide a filename to save it to, including a path, and macs have a different way of specifying a path. Presumably that means you would have to change that part of the code, but since you did not include any of the actual code you are using in your question, getting help that is more specific than that is going to prove to be difficult.

Comment: I used the example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer - i haven’t posted it simply because urldownloadtofile references urlmon which is a windows only dll so there is no way it will work on Mac. So I was wondering if there was a Mac alternative way to do something similar to download images files