# Getting a relevant details from web via code

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Hi i am new to VBA and trying to upgrade my skills in VBA.

I am trying to getting the "Owner Name" and "Mailing Address" from this below web link

https://www.pbcgov.org/papa/Asps/PropertyDetail/PropertyDetail.aspx?parcel=30424032060001820

by using this ID in Sheet1"A1"

30-42-40-32-06-000-1820 ( that ID is the relevant to a person which name and mailing address will be paste in Col"B" and Col"C".

I have tried but could not make it.

Any help by anybody will be appreciated.

```
Sub Data()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    Url = "https://www.pbcgov.org/papa/?fbclid=IwAR28Ao4d0Ic5hTcd4w6BYv5FwaVYKFc3sCtmcqPI8Ctw2Q0jUy2zIdc7I-c"

    'Wait for site to fully load
    ie.Navigate2 Url
    
    Do While ie.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    RowCount = 1

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        RowCount = 1
        For Each itm In ie.document.all
            .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
            .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
            .Range("c" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Next itm
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Some tips are in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796559/vba-internet-explorer-application-gives-different-results-for-each-function-call

Comment: I agree with QHarr's answer. I test it and it can achieve what you want. I suggest that you can mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a little advanced but gives another way of looking at the problem.

The info you want is spread over two tables, and two rows within those tables. One table for the owner info (split across several lines); and one table, likewise, for address.

You can use [css pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) `#ownerInformationDiv table:nth-child(1)` to isolate both of those tables, returned in a nodeList by applying [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method of `ie.document`.

Loop each table, and whilst in a given table, loop the rows (ignoring the header row) and concatenate the text found in each row. Once the text is combined, for a given table, write it out to the sheet.

Another things to note include:

The full page load wait

```
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
```

Qualifying object with class

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

Use of a descriptive title

```
Public Sub WriteOutOwnersInfo()
```

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutOwnersInfo()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.pbcgov.org/papa/Asps/PropertyDetail/PropertyDetail.aspx?parcel=30424032060001820"
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim tables As Object
        
        Set tables = .Document.querySelectorAll("#ownerInformationDiv table:nth-child(1)")
 
        Dim currTable As Object, currRow As Object, c As Long
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, lineOutput As String
        
        For i = 0 To tables.Length - 1
            Set currTable = tables.Item(i)
            lineOutput = vbNullString
            
            For j = 1 To tables.Item(i).Rows.Length - 1
                Set currRow = currTable.Rows(j)
                lineOutput = lineOutput & Chr$(32) & Trim$(currRow.innertext)
            Next
            c = c + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, c) = Trim$(lineOutput)
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr, Thank you so much