# WinHttpRequest gzip response parsing

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, winhttp

I'm using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` for http surfing in my VBA project. The issue is `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` is limited to four concurrent requests.

I'm trying to use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` instead, and there is another issue. `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` parses gzip result automatically, but 
`WinHttpRequest.responseText` method fails with error:

> No mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

How can I parse this result with standard Windows libraries?

Code examples:
MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 limitation:

```
Public req1 As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Public req2 As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Public req3 As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Public req4 As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Public req5 As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Private Const url As String = "http://speedtest.tele2.net/100MB.zip"


Public Sub ConcurrentIssue()
    Set req1 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    req1.Open "get", url, True

    Set req2 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    req2.Open "get", url, True

    Set req3 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    req3.Open "get", url, True

    Set req4 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    req4.Open "get", url, True

    Set req5 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    req5.Open "get", url, True

    req1.send
    req2.send
    req3.send
    req4.send

    'This query will be wait
    req5.send

End Sub
```

Problem is that `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` does not support decompression (proof link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh227298(v=vs.85).aspx).
I need to decompress the response myself.

Decompression issue example:

```
Public Sub DecompressOk()
    Set req1 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    req1.Open "get", "http://www.google.ru", False
    req1.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Fiddler"
    req1.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    req1.send

    Debug.Print req1.responseText
End Sub

Public Sub WithoutDecompress()
    Dim req As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    req.Open "get", "http://www.google.ru", False
    req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Fiddler"
    req.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    req.send

    Debug.Print req.responseText
End Sub
```

I was trying to do this trick without success:

```
Public Sub DecompressIssue()
    Dim req As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    req.Open "get", "http://www.google.ru", False
    req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Fiddler"
    req.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    req.send

    SaveBinaryToFile req.responseBody, "C:\test.zip"

    Dim xmlReq As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xmlReq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    xmlReq.Open "get", "C:\test.zip", False
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=windows-1251"
    xmlReq.send

    Debug.Print xmlReq.responseBody
End Sub

Sub SaveBinaryToFile(arrBytes() As Byte, strPath As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write arrBytes
        .SaveToFile strPath, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit and add a minimal code. The question should be [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others could reproduce the issues for both 4 concurrent requests `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` limitation and "No mapping" error for `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`.

Comment: Some webpages may contain unreadable characters, try to get binary content from `WinHttpRequest.responseBody`, and then convert it to the text via `ADODB.Sream` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484763/2165759).

Comment: Try to make XHR with `.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "identity"` to force the webserver to send uncompressed response.

Comment: I was trying to do it, but server freezes. I cannot influence on it.

Answer (score 2):

*<sup>This answer confirms [the comment made by omegastripes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193488/winhttprequest-gzip-response-parsing-issue/59812598#comment75480730_44193488).</sup>*

`.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "identity"` is the right answer!

I've searched for days for a way to decode the gzipped response, but wasn't aware we could tell the server to not compress the response.