# VBA automate ie11 save as dialogue box

Tags: vba, automation, internet-explorer-11, sendkeys, save-as

I'm one step away from success on a huge automation project. I've got a dynamic download automated all the way up to the IE11 Save As dialogue box. This is where I'm stuck. I need to 1) enter in a dynamic file name and save to a dynamic folder (all based on a cell value). 2) click Save while overriding any update dialogue boxes

Limitations; I cant download based on the URL if you were going to suggest that. I'm dealing with a secure site and a funky URL that can only be accessed via the For Next loop I have below. I'm limited to dealing with this SaveAs box as far as I'm aware.

Here's what I have so far;

```
Sub savedownload()


Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate Sheet3.Range("A1").Value ' this is where the dynamic URL is updated
 Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 objIE.document.getElementById("PrintFormat").Value = "Pdf"
 Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


Dim list As Object, item As Object
Set list = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each item In list
If item.innerText = "Export" Then
    item.Click
    Exit For
End If
Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
Application.SendKeys "{RETURN}", True

'this is where the dialoge box comes up, but I cant seem to send a dynamic string of text to the file name/path field

End Sub
```

I have attached a screenshot as well. Would send keys work? Is there a way to call the SaveAs window and drop in a dynamic file name? I can throw a file name at it and get it to save with SendKeys, but I'm thinking there's a better way where I can send an entire dynamic String to the FileName field in the dialogue box.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Screenshot of IE11 SaveAs dialogue box

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32253563/2165759) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33462100/2165759).